# I cannot curl my Spring Boot Kotlin Service

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have put this in the SecurityConfig.

Swagger and Postman work fine, but I cannot Curl from the Terminal. I thought the config would allow this.

This is my code

```
      

    

    @Bean
   
    fun localDatabaseSecurityConfigurer() : AdditionalSecurityConfigurer{

        return AdditionalSecurityConfigurer{http, mvcBuilder ->
            http
                .csrf{ csrf ->
                    csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console())
                    csrf.disable()

                }
                .authorizeHttpRequests{auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers(mvcBuilder.pattern("/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()
                }
                .headers {h -> h.frameOptions {f -> f.disable()}}
        }
```

Comment: If your service works via Postman, on the Right side of Postman you will find a `</>` option use this to export the curl command (https://codingnconcepts.com/postman/how-to-generate-curl-command-from-postman/).  Try running that.  Then compare with the curl command you were testing.  If you don't understand the difference update your Question with both these curl commands.